# Code runs then at the last input it will close the window, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing code for an "ATM" for my my coding class. I have the code doing what i want all the way up until the logout input. At that point it will close the window before showing the "successful logout". I am very new to python so i am unaware if this is normal or if something in my code is off. I am sure there is a much better way of writing my code all together but from what i know at this point this is the best i could do.

```
funds = 500

while True:
  print("\nMenu Options:\n\n1: Withdraw Money\n2: Deposit Money\n3: View Balance\n4: Logout\n\n") 
  user_input = int(input("Enter Option: "));

  #Withdraw process
  while user_input == 1:
    amount = int(input("\n  Enter Withdraw Amount: $"))
    while amount > funds:
      print("\nInsufficient Funds")
      break
    else:
      funds -= amount
      print("\nSuccessful Withdraw of $", amount)
      break

  #Deposit process
  while user_input == 2:
    amount = int(input("\n  Enter Deposit Amount: $"))
    funds += amount
    print("\nSuccessful Deposit of $", amount)
    break

  #View balance process
  while user_input == 3:
    print("\nAvailable Balance: $",funds)
    break

  #Logout process
  if user_input == 4:
    print("\nSuccessful Logout!")
    break


  #Wrong menu option input process
  while user_input > 4:
    break
```

Comment: Small tip: Try to replace all `while` keywords (except the `while True`) with `if` statement ( :

Comment: you're probably running your code by double clicking on the file, instead open a command prompt/terminal and type `python my_script.py`

Comment: How are you running your Python script? Are you on Windows (bless your soul)?

Comment: I was running the code by double clicking the file.. This code was written using repl.it. I  am on windows and when i click the file it runs on a command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Open up a file with only the statement:

```py
print("Hello world!")
```

You'll notice that python.exe opens and closes almost immediately. That's because the job of the Python script is to simply print "Hello world!" to the console. Once that's done, it has no business staying around and so it exits.

In your code, as soon as "Successful Logout!" is printed, the `break` statement breaks the flow of the program out of the top level `while True:` loop, and since there are no other statements to execute, it closes the console.

To get around this, you can use an `input("Press any key to exit.")` before your `break` so that you get a chance to see your output before the program exits.

Also, your code is perfectly functional! I'm sure there are more things you'll find out about Python as you go along. Like knowing when to use `while break` and when to use `if elif else`. But for now, as long as your code does what you tell it to, you're good to go!

Comment: Thank you so much I tried it and it seems to work! and yes slowly learning and making the most of these older discussion questions on here.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please consider marking it as accepted.